# SVG visibility issues in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, opera

Because of design issues I'm required to use SVG to draw all the elements of the interface (buttons, text, icons, etc) of an html application. Most of them are visible right from the start, but others, like menus, have their visibility set to hidden.

The problem is, while in the other browsers you click on the button and all the SVG elements of the hidden menu become visible, in Opera only the dynamic elements are shown. For some reason the visibility is not being applied to the children of the said menu unless you give them an id and manually apply a class to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to force the visibility onto all the children of the menu:

```
$("#menu").css({"visibility": "visible"});    

$('#menu').children().each(function() {
    $(this).css({"visibility": "visible"});
});
```